# Access-Control-Allow-Origin missing

Tags: javascript, java, rest, cors

i'am developing a REST api and consumes it via my browser(firefox), but i'm getting this error

> Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://localhost:8080/siga/av. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing).

i'm using embedded jetty 9 for deploiement.

My methode:

```
@GET
@Path("av")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN)
@Override
public Response avoidCrossDomain() {
    return Response.status(Status.FOUND).entity("hello").header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*").build();
}
```

Postman Response :

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin →*
>
> Content-Length →5
>
> Content-Type →text/plain
>
> Date →Mon, 29 Jan 2018 07:58:28 GMT
>
> Server →Jetty(9.2.3.v20140905)

Javascript

```
$.ajax({

url: 'http://localhost:8080/siga/av',
type: 'GET',
crossDomain: true,
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(data) { alert("data"); },
error: function() { alert('Failed!'); },
});
```

Comment: i tried that, and it did not work, same problem persist

Answer (score 0):

You have to define the CORS filter for jetty in the `web.xml`:

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.eclipse.jetty.servlets.CrossOriginFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
<filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>cross-origin</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

You can find further information concerning the CORS filter in the [jetty documentation](http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/documentation/current/cross-origin-filter.html)

Comment: thank you for your reply, but i'm using embedded jetty